# Elasticsearch / Tire - Flattening Nested Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapping, elasticsearch, tire

In reference to the [Query DSL Explained Tutorial Slides 14-15](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/28/query-dsl-explained.html)

How do I flatten Nested Objects?

I have a Model named `Entry` and another named `Category` and they share a HABTM association.
Everything is currently working and the search results seem to be correct, but I don't know if my mapping is correct. The tutorial says that when you flatten objects the Document will look like this :

```
{
    tweet      => "Perl is GREAT!",
    posted     => "2011-08-15",
    user.name  => "Clinton Gormley",
    user.email => "drtech@cpan.org",
    tags       => ["perl","opinion"],
    posts      => 2,
}
```

with the Object `user` being flattened. When I look at the source of my JSON document it looks like this:

```
{
"title":"First",
"description":"first test",
"categories":
    {"categories_name":"CAP and Using the CAP website"},
"attachment":"VEVTVCE=\n",
"published":true
}
```

So, I'm assuming that its supposed to say `categories.categories_name` but I don't know how to specify that or if that's even necessary. Here's some Model code:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  mount_uploader :doc, EntryDocUploader

  tire.mapping do
      indexes :title  
      indexes :description
      indexes :categories do
        indexes :categories_name, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
      end
      indexes :attachment, :type => 'attachment', 
                    :fields => {
                    :title    => { :store => 'yes' },
                    :attachment     => { :term_vector => 'with_positions_offsets', :store => 'yes' }
                    }
  end

 def to_indexed_json
    {
    :title          => title,
    :description    => description,
    :categories     => {:categories_name => cats}, #categories.map { |c| { :categories_name => c.name}}.to_sentence,
    :attachment      => attachment,
    }.to_json
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      filter :term, :published => "true"
    end
  end

  def cats
    categories.map(&:name).to_sentence
  end

end
```

Comment: It looks right to me.  I think the dot notation is just shorthand.

Comment: Well, testing it with a few entries seems to work just fine, so you're probably right. I was just worried that it would affect speed and results later on, if it wasn't exactly right. but thanks @DaveS!